# Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly when using DjangoChannelsGraphqlWs

Tags: python, websocket, graphene-python

Whenever I try to subscribe I get TypeError: Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly."
}

Here is the traceback

```
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Exercises\lssya\backend\env\Lib\site-packages\promise\promise.py", line 87, in try_catch
    return (handler(*args, **kwargs), None)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Exercises\lssya\backend\env\Lib\site-packages\graphql\execution\executor.py", line 127, in promise_executor
    return execute_operation(exe_context, exe_context.operation, root_value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Exercises\lssya\backend\env\Lib\site-packages\graphql\execution\executor.py", line 180, in execute_operation
    return subscribe_fields(exe_context, type, root_value, fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Exercises\lssya\backend\env\Lib\site-packages\graphql\execution\executor.py", line 297, in subscribe_fields
    result = subscribe_field(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Exercises\lssya\backend\env\Lib\site-packages\graphql\execution\executor.py", line 422, in subscribe_field
    raise result
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Exercises\lssya\backend\env\Lib\site-packages\graphql\execution\executor.py", line 452, in resolve_or_error
    return executor.execute(resolve_fn, source, info, **args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Exercises\lssya\backend\env\Lib\site-packages\graphql\execution\executors\asyncio.py", line 74, in execute
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Exercises\lssya\backend\env\Lib\site-packages\channels_graphql_ws\graphql_ws_consumer.py", line 596, in register_middleware
    return next_middleware(root, info, *args, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Exercises\lssya\backend\env\Lib\site-packages\channels_graphql_ws\subscription.py", line 434, in _subscribe
    return register_subscription(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Exercises\lssya\backend\env\Lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 277, in __call__
    return call_result.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Exercises\lssya\backend - Copy - Copy\env\Lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 353, in main_wrap
    result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Exercises\lssya\backend - Copy - Copy\env\Lib\site-packages\channels_graphql_ws\graphql_ws_consumer.py", line 767, in _register_subscription
    await asyncio.wait(waitlist)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 415, in wait
    raise TypeError("Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly.")
TypeError: Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly.
```

This is  my consumer

```
class MyGraphqlWsConsumer(channels_graphql_ws.GraphqlWsConsumer):
    
    send_keepalive_every = 30

    async def on_connect(self, payload):
        self.scope['user'] = await channels.auth.get_user(self.scope)

    
    
    schema = schema
```

and my subscription is

```
class OnNewMessage(channels_graphql_ws.Subscription):
    message = graphene.Field(MessageType)

    class Arguments:
        chatroom = graphene.String()

    def subscribe(self, info, chatroom=None):
        """Client subscription handler."""
        del info
        # Specify the subscription group client subscribes to.
        return [chatroom] if chatroom is not None else None

    def publish(self, info, chatroom=None):
        return OnNewMessage(
            message=self
        )
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but that `del info` statement is useless.  That doesn't delete the object, it just removes the name `info` from the function's namespace.  We don't have enough information to address your actual problem.  And what is `publish` trying to do?  Does the `OnNewMessage` constructor really expect an `OnNewMessage` instance to be passed in?